# DownloadManager with custom Uri

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-download-manager

I have my own custom Uri which looks like:

```
stream://com.mydomain.myprovider/[blah-blah]
```

Basically it points to SQLite record with some blob

For sure I do have custom `ContentProvider` which handles this kind of `Uri`

My intention is to use `DownloadManager` for downloading bytes/blobs as file.

Direct try to use `DownloadManager` fired exception saying that supported protocol are only `HTTP/HTTPS`.

How to achieve my goal?

Comment: Um, if it is your own `ContentProvider` and your own database, use standard Java file I/O to write your own content out to your own file.

Comment: Sure, it's option, but I just thought I could use more elegant solution using `DownloadManager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DownloadManager` is for downloading files from the Internet using Web URLs (`http` and `https`). It is not a general-purpose "hey, let's write a file!" service.

For your own content in your own database fronted by your own `ContentProvider`, write your own Java I/O code to write your own bytes to your own file.